# Which is correct in this sentence - 'to inhibit', 'inhibit', or 'inhibits'?

Tags: infinitives

> What this medication does is (**to inhibit** / **inhibit** / **inhibits**) the reproduction of the certain kinds of bacteria.

Comment: It might be helpful to respondents if you provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like which one you think is right and your reasoning.

Comment: "What this medication does is inhibits the reproduction of the certain kinds of bacteria" - That would be the correct sentence.
You should provide more details, that what is the actual problem you are facing in this sentence?

Comment: @HassanAshas "What this medication does is inhibits the reproduction" is not correct. It should be "inhibit".

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence is:

> What this medication does is (to) inhibit the reproduction of certain kinds of bacteria.

According to The Free Dictionary, you can use an infinitive with or without to after the construction What + subject + do + be. However, the infinitive without to is more common.

Comment: Do you have the link to that page TFD? It might be helpful for folks that want to read a little more about it.

Comment: @ColleenV, Listing #7.(used in relative clauses), The Free Dictionary.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/what

Answer (score 0):

To inhibit is the one I would choose, similar like it is to prevent incidents. "is" is one of Be verbs, there are be+doing/adjective, without "is" it should be "inhibits" as "What this medication does" equals "it". Then verb can't follow by another verb unless it is connected by "to" like "I am **going to camp** at the forest". Actually, I have joust found something that can explain what I had written in a professional and technical way[Functions of the to-infinitive](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/)which is shared by Davyd Diniz

Comment: Could you please explain *why* you would choose this?

Comment: Hi Chenmunka, I have added the explanation to my initial answer

Answer (score 0):

I would say it as

What this medication does is ***,it inhibits*** the reproduction of the certain kinds of bacteria.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please [edit] to include an explanation of why this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence can be reordered as:

> [ (to inhibit / inhibit / inhibits) the reproduction of the certain kinds of bacteria ] **is what this medication does**

In this view, the fragment must stand on its own as a **noun phrase (the subject)**, and **to inhibit** has this property. However, after "is", "inhibit" also works. You can find examples on the web by searching  "what this * do is" in google books.

Then "inhibit" or "to inhibit" work.